# Установить тэг для ImageButton

Tags: android

В приложении постоянно меняется картинка на ImageButton, и чтобы узнать какая именно сейчас установлена решил к каждой заранее добавить тэг. Подскажите как это сделать, либо есть какие-то альтернативные варианты?

Comment: а в чем конкретно проблема?  если вопрос в том как прикрепить тэг - то imageView.setTag("yourTag");

Comment: @KirillStoianov, заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но как это сделать для определенной картинки, которая лежит в папке drawable?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `setTag()` для установки и `getTag` для получения тэга.

Можете по-своему сделать,  картинки же меняются по какой-то логике, запоминать в той части, а затем брать данные. Если вообще хотите получить какая была последняя/предыдущие картинки, можете писать в `SharedPreferences`,  потом прочитаете в любом месте приложения, даже если этой кнопки уже нет.